# Big O Time complexity for Find All Numbers Disappeared in an Array

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, time-complexity, big-o

During the moment I was solving this code exercise. I couldn't figure out if my current solution is still on O(n) runtime.

Below I present my solution.

**Find All Numbers Disappeared in an Array**

Give an array of integers where 1 <= a[i] <= n (n = size of array), some elements appear twice and others appear once.

Find all the elements of [1, n] inclusive that do not appear in this array

Could you do it without extra space and in O(n) runtime?

**Example:**

Input: 
[4, 3, 2, 7, 8, 2, 3, 1]

Output:
[5, 6]

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    findAllNumbersDisappeared(new int[] { 4,3,2,7,8,2,3,1});
}

/* the idea is that since we have a size _n_ array and it has numbers from 1 to n, 
 * given that are repeated numbers, we can iterate over the array and 
 * keep placing the elements in the position equal to their value 
 * (i.e. 1 is placed in the first position, 2 in the second, 3 in the third, and so on)
 * Once that is done by swapping the elements, we iterate over the array again and 
 * compare the position with the value at that position. 
 * 
 * For the positions where they don't match, 
 * it means that whereas it should ideally have had the same value at that position (if there were no repeats), 
 * that positional value represents the missing number.
 * */
public static void findAllNumbersDisappeared(int[] arr) {
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        while (arr[i] != (i+1) && arr[i] != arr[arr[i]-1]) {
            swap(arr, i, arr[i]-1);
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if (arr[i] != (i+1)) {
            System.out.println(i+1);
        }
    }
}

private static void swap(int[] arr, int i, int j) {
    int t = arr[i];
    arr[i] = arr[j];
    arr[j] = t;
}
```

Probably I'm confused on Big O theory. The first loop is iterated on N items (where N is the length of the array, so this is O(n)), the inner while is not executed more than N times on the whole program flow.

I don't consider this program is O(n^2), I think is between O(n) and O(n log n). Can you support me to determine the right time complexity for this solution?

Comment: What is the purpose of `while (arr[i] != (i+1) && arr[i] != arr[arr[i]-1])` section?

Comment: That section is the question re: big-O.  The for loops otherwise are just O(n).

Comment: @Joe It's a check where it says: if the current number match with its index, leave as it is; if not, do a swap. That's the meaning of that condition. So it'll be swaping the number until it matches or finds a cycle.

Comment: I can't tell for sure because your code has some obvious bugs (for example your swap could refer to array element -1) and you don't really explain your algorithm well enough -- what do you expect the array to look like after the first `for` loop is finished?

Comment: @Joe In the second for loop, it can determine which numbers are missing on the array. For example, following the same sample:

[4,3,2,7,8,2,3,1] becomes => [1,2,3,4,3,2,7,8] during the first for loop. 
So the second for loop check which numbers are not matching with its index (i+1 as the list starts from 1)

Comment: It's O(n). I ran a test with random integers 100 times, and the number of swaps was always `<= N`. [Here's the Ideone Test](https://ideone.com/QFeR2L).

Comment: @oscar.fimbres As you said, the `while` is your implementation of *"**if** the ..."*. `while` vs `if`. When would that ever loop a *second* time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your solution is O(N), but I don't think it is correct.  (Test it!)

Hint: there is a O(N) algorithm that genuinely solves the problem.

- Consider how you represent a set of numbers as a bitmap.
- Consider the "clock patience" card game (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clock_Patience)

(These hints are designed to get you thinking in the right direction.  I think you may already be mostly there, but I want you to get to the right solution for yourself.  To maximize the learning / self-confidence-building.)

Comment: Perhaps I'm just missing the algorithm you're intending to go for, but doesn't what you're describing use linear space for all the bits needed?

Comment: Not with a little bit of thought.  You already have a data structure that can act like that bitmap.  Consider `a[i] = i + 1` as `true` and `a[i] != i + 1` as `false`.  Like I said, the OP is "almost there" in his solution.